# Jenkins - Publish Over FTP Plugin - Selecting a different Folder / Path

Tags: jenkins, ftp, publish

I have tested many scenario and I continue to hit the wall at the end of the day.

I see that the Publish Over FTP Plugin is able to send the files (*.txt) to my ftp when I leave the field "Transfer Set Source Files" only with the search criteria *.txt beacuse it is searching all files under the workspace (/opt/jenkins/workspace/PROJECT_NAME).

But although is said that 'while a pattern like ../foo.java is possible' it seems that doesn't really work as I cannot get the file which I have placed on /opt/jenkins/workspace.

My goal is to locate all txt files under /home/user/aFolder/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not found the solution which I was expected I had to apply a symlink inside the workspace/ to the location where I want to collect the file. Using this approach I could solve my question